# How to allow any user to run stored procedure in shared hosting mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, shared-hosting

When creating stored procedure in MySQL database hosted on **shared hosting** server, a definer for the procedure automatically added:
**CREATE DEFINER=`teq_user1`@`My IP Address` PROCEDURE `dpr_tax`(IN...** 
this limits calling this procedure from this IP only.
We need to allow certain user to call this procedure regardless the IP.

I have tried:
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE teq_acc.dpr_tax TO 'teq_user1'@'%';

 and 
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE teq_acc.dpr_tax TO 'teq_user1'@'localhost';

but following error received:
grant command denied to user 'teq_user1'@'My IP address'

Comment: i think you are looking for `DEFINER = CURRENT_USER` instead ... Then you can more or less simply grant EXECUTE priv to the MySQL user which could be able to use this..  But not 100% sure as i am unsure how you are using this..

Comment: @RaymondNijland , thanks for your support,
The problem is not the user but the IP. it's dedicated to the user but should be from certain IP and I couldn't grant privilege to `user`@`%` as I am in shared environment.

Comment: opening up MySQL or allow connection from any IP on the internet, which is what you are looking for is a bad idea anyway.. You need some kind of gateway (sockets or webservice based) which sits between your application and the MySQL server..

Comment: @RaymondNijland .. Could this done through SSH or what else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix: 
**"DEFINER=teq_user1@My IP Address"**
is added when you create stored procedure from a client app connected via **"Remote SQL"** such as MySQL Workbench. But if you re-created the procedure from **PHPmyAdmin**, Definer will be: 
**"DEFINER=teq_user1@localhost"** 
which can be run from any IP.