# why does an IP-specific DEFINER clause prevent other MySQL accounts executing code objects?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Chapeau to anyone who can help with this. We have encountered a problem with the DEFINER clause in MySQL. Our MySQL is on a hosted server.

Here are two sample error messages that have apeared in client apps (to which no clients can currently log in)

```
Statement exec failed: execute command denied to user 'auditrec_ABC'@'%' for routine 'auditrec_VDA_test.usp_log_SQL'
Statement exec failed: execute command denied to user 'auditrec_ABC'@'%' for routine 'auditrec_BCS_test2.usp_getCredentials'
```

The auditrec_ABC account is NOT being used when these statements are executed. I have added 'SELECT CURRENT_USER()' to augment the error info and confirm the account in use is auditrec_XYZ@localhost

```
Statement exec has failed: execute command denied to user 'auditrec_ABC'@'%' for routine 'auditrec_VDA_test.usp_log_SQL'; account: auditrec_XYZ@localhost
```

The problem is almost certainly that the auditrec_ABC acount is referred to in the DEFINER clause of the definition of the code objects that cannot be executed.

This error only arose after I came back from holiday and my home IP address had changed. The vast majority of our routines include DEFINER=`auditrec_ABC`@`82.1.124.70` with 82.1.124.70 being my old IP address (not the real one)

It is default behavior for MySQL to add a DEFINER clause - it can't be avoided.

Here's an example

```
CREATE DEFINER=`auditrec_ABC`@`82.1.124.70` PROCEDURE `usp_log_SQL`( ...)
```

I get it that MySQL now sees me as `auditrec_ABC`@`82.1.195.23` - **but not why that stops other accounts from executing code objects they previously executed?**

This S.O. article suggests the way we will possibly have to go

[How to allow any user to run stored procedure in shared hosting mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58804313/how-to-allow-any-user-to-run-stored-procedure-in-shared-hosting-mysql)

(that will involve re-declaring thousands of code objects)

And this S.O. article maybe offers a little glimmer of an alternative

[Possible to have multiple users as DEFINER for MySQL Stored Procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35511862/possible-to-have-multiple-users-as-definer-for-mysql-stored-procedure)

but we do not have the permissions we need to make the GRANT statements, nor to execute for example

```
UPDATE `mysql`.`proc` p SET definer = 'YournewDefiner' WHERE definer='OldDefinerShownBefore'
```

And crucially, we don't understand why we should need to change the DEFINER statements: WHY, if the DEFINER account suddenly accesses MySQL from at a different IP address, can all the other accounts no longer execute the code objects?

Comment: You do not have a problem alone with the definer clause as it simply states which user account was used to create the stored proc. The problem is that the other user account does not have execute privilege for the given stored proc. You need to grant the user in question execute access on the stored proc.

Comment: please can I assure you, the other user account DOES have execute privilege for the given stored procedure (indeed, for the whole DB that contains it). Everything worked fine until my IP address changed. If I recreate a specific stored procedure (so that the IP address in the DEFINER statement reflects my new IP address), it fixes the presenting problem for that procedure.

Comment: I'm sorry, but between your assurance and the mysql error message, I'll go with the latter! You have to keep in mind that username@% and username@ip_address are two different user accounts that can have different access rights! I wonder if username@ip_address has the execute right, while the % user does not.

Comment: Shadow, I appreciate that the error message suggests I am a dumb ass, and it has been known, but on this occasion I have counter evidence to offer (beyond adding SELECT CURRENT_USER() to the error output)

Using PHPMyAdmin to re-declare any DB object that prompts the error eliminates the problem. PHPMyAdmin resets the DEFINER to `s56dfpg5v47va`@`localhost`. No execute permissions are changed on any account. I am not changing any code, I am simply exporting it and re-running it in PHPMyAdmin so that the DEFINER is different, and everything runs again

Comment: Changing definer may impact which users may need execute access rights to  the stored proc if the security context is also definer and not invoker.